# Can my UK limited company claim tax relief on donations to foreign charities?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, tax-deduction, charity, charitable-contributions

I'm English, and run a company that's based in the UK and registered with the UK Companies House. I want to donate some money to charity, but one of the charities I have in mind isn't based in the UK. (Specifically, it's in the USA.)

It's clear (and obvious) that any donations I make to British charities will be tax-deductible, but what about donations to foreign charities? Can I still claim tax relief on these donations? I've had a look through gov.uk and can't find a clear answer.

Comment: http://www.accountingweb.co.uk/anyanswers/tax-relief-donations-foreign-charity     http://www.accountingweb.co.uk/anyanswers/can-uk-company-get-corporation-tax-relief-donations-hong-kong-charity